# Getting key.code from characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I've a list of characters:

```
+ * & # @
```

How do I read them in jquery so that I can disable on keypress?

```
 $(document).on("keydown", ".quick-edit", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == &) {
           return false;
        }
    });
```

To rephrase my question, I want to know charCode from string `&`

Comment: if ( "+ * & # @".indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))!== -1) { ...

Comment: `String.fromCharCode` is a more semantic approach

Comment: @Xander I need the reverse, I need charcode from string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.which` will give the homoginized code for the pressed key, then you can use a array of disabled keycodes to prevent the default action.

```
var disabled = [55, 107, 106]
$(document).on("keydown", ".quick-edit", function (e) {
    console.log(e.which)
    if($.inArray(e.which, disabled)!=-1){
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charcodeat.asp

```
var str = "$";
var n = str.charCodeAt(0);
```